# How to join two table to expand certain row multiple times

Tags: sql-server, join

`table 1`

```
Places              Type
All Places          Food
All Places          Dessert
...
```

`table 2`

```
Places              Weather
JH                  Cloudy
Martin              Sunny
Jones               Rainy
Brownsville         Sunny
Nashville           Sunny
```

How can I take the `table 2` column `Places` and join it with `table 1`

I would like `table 1` to be (Example: expand `All Places` to have every place from `table 2` with the `Food` type):

```
Places              Type
JH                  Food
Martin              Food
Jones               Food
Brownsville         Food
Nashville           Food
JH                  Dessert
Martin              Dessert
Jones               Dessert
Brownsville         Dessert
Nashville           Dessert
...
```

I am using MS Sql server 2012.

Update:

`table 1`

```
Specialty                                          Topic
Infectious Disease                                 Not Satisfied
Pediatrics                                         Advice / Triage
All Specialties                                    After Hours
All Specialties                                    Age Restrictions
OBGYN                                              Alpha- Feto Protein
```

`table 2`

```
Specialty                                 Version
All Specialties                           All Specialties
OBGYN                                     2.0
Pediatrics                                1.1
Infectious Disease                        0.9
```

`table 1` should be updated to this:

```
Specialty                                 Topic
Infectious Disease                        Not Satisfied
Pediatrics                                Advice / Triage
OBGYN                                     After Hours
Pediatrics                                After Hours
Infectious Disease                        After Hours
OBGYN                                     Age Restrictions
Pediatrics                                Age Restrictions
Infectious Disease                        Age Restrictions
OBGYN                                     Alpha- Feto Protein
```

Comment: _"every place from table 2 with the Food type"_ but table2 has no `Type` column. It's not clear how you want to join the tables.

Comment: I am sorry. The resulted table is what I am looking to be the end product for `table 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a `Cartesian product`

```
SELECT b.places,
       a.type
FROM   table1 a
       CROSS JOIN table2 b
WHERE  a.places = 'All Places'
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT b.places,
       a.type
FROM   table1 a
       CROSS JOIN table2 b
WHERE  a.places = 'All Places'
union 
select places,type from 
table1 
where places <> 'All Places'
```

Comment: Where should the UPDATE statement go? I would like `table 1` to update with the new data as shown in the last table. Thanks by the way :)

Comment: That didn't work. What it should do is for each topic which has All Places, each place should be entered for the Type. But instead it is multiplying the Places as many times Food appears.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - not sure what you are talking about. But here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cdf7f3/1 it comes with exact expected output

Comment: I am sorry I updated my question to update `table 1` and to show what is happening. I still want to see all the other entries which doesn't have `All Places`. I would like `All Places` to be replaced with all the places from `table 2` with the same type. So `Food` will repeat but no `Place`. I hope I am clearer now.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - updated check now. Demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d4bb7/1

Comment: Thank you for being patient. Here is the real data sqlfiddle `table 2`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/358f9/1. `table 2` has a All Specialties entry as well but I would like to disregard that. So `All Specialties` with `After Hours` should not be included` in the updated `table 1`

Comment: I have updated my question with real data so you can better understand. Thanks.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/358f9/1 worked great. Thank you. Can you please show me how to exclude the All Speciaties from `table 2`?